# Android access SQLite database from multiple process through service

Tags: android, sqlite, service, multiprocess

Every app in android has separate process. By-default same android app components runs in same process.

Consider for ex. if App1 started then it will start in Process1, similarly App2 has Process2. Then if I start service from App1 it will start into its process i.e. Process1. 
I have one library with one background unbounded service. Through that service I am doing the CRUD operations in SQLite database file. 
So for we have Process1(with its background Service1) and Process2(with its background Service2). 
My question is How to make this SQLite database access Process-safe/Thread-safe(which runs in different Main thread by-default). The most searches are fails to explain how to handle this, please guide me in correct way.

Comment: What you are talking about is solved by using a ContentProvider.  Create one of these to manage your database and build it as a separate APK.

Comment: 1. The lib is offered to other apps(which obvious unknown apps), 2. Here is what doc says http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#ThreadSafe

Comment: If your ContentProvider (which I am still suggesting is the solution here) is backed by a SQLite Database, access to the SQLiteDatabase itself IS thread-safe.

Comment: "Every app in android has separate process." I started reading this question and stopped after this first sentence which is false.